# Nginx file encoding cache

Tags: caching, encoding, nginx

It appears that my Nginx configuration has some issues with caching of Javascript files.  If I edit as JS file it gets served by Nginx as http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=C3XY9T8d, obbiouvsly there is a problem with file encoding.  If I reboot the server or wait a while (not sure how long, definitely longer than 10 minutes) the file gets served correctly without the '�' characters.

Is there an option to change this so that the files aren't somehow cached and showing up with a wonky encoding?

I've tried `open_file_cache off;` and that solved some previous issues I had but it doesn't help here.  Also on a whim I tried `chunked_transfer_encoding off;` but that doesn't seem to be related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue with running in a VM.  Apparently "sendfile doesn't play nice with VMs".  Adding `sendfile off` into config has solved this problem.